# ASP.NET Only edit the last item from every type

Tags: mysql, sql, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

Hey I have a RoadRecord table. I have an SQL database for it. I display it on Index.html. In the RoadRecords there are date,LicencePlate, Type, Fuel, Mileage etc.., User can edit these RoadRecords. But here is the problem, how can I implement that user only can edit the newest record for each Licenceplate.
For example:

| Date | LicencePlate |
| --- | --- |
| 08.19 | AAA-111 |
| 08.17 | AAA-111 |
| 08.16 | CCC-222 |

In this situation I should be able to edit only the 08.19 AAA-111, and the 08.16 CCC-222.
There is any way to implement it in code or in SQL?

Here is my table in .html

```
<tbody>
            @foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                <tr class="click box-shadow" onclick="location.href = '@(Url.Action("Details", "RoadRecords", new { id = item.Id }))'">
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Date)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LicencePlateNavigation.LicencePlate)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.User.Name)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Location)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Mileage)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Fueling)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Note)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <a asp-action="Edit" asp-route-id="@item.Id">Szerkesztés</a> |
                        <!--<a asp-action="Details" asp-route-id="@item.Id">Részletek</a> | -->
                        <a asp-action="Delete" asp-route-id="@item.Id">Törlés</a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
```

**EDIT 1 - Did it in SQL Manager Studio**

I got it in SQL Manager Studio, now, how can I implement it in EntityFramework, or in code?

```
SELECT * FROM [RoadRecord]  WHERE [Date] IN ( SELECT MAX([Date]) FROM [RoadRecord] GROUP BY [LicencePlate]);
```

Comment: I guess an easy solution would be to introduce a boolean variable named e.g. "first" outside the foreach loop.
`bool first = true;`
Then set it to false at the end of the foreach loop. It will only be true in the first iteration.
Base the visibility of the edit button on this.

Comment: But the Model is @model IEnumerable<MainProject.Models.RoadRecord>, so in foreach, I loop on every RoadRecords, and I want to edit the first from every Licence Plate. What you saying is only show the first from the RoadRecords, like .FirstOrDefault()

Answer (score 0):

You can use this linq to select the newest `datatime` goupby `LicencePlate`

```
var result = _dbContext.RoadRecords.GroupBy(x => x.LicencePlate).Select(x=>x.Max(z=>z.Date)).ToList();
```

I write a simple demo here.

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
     private readonly ProductDbContext _dbContext;

     public HomeController(ProductDbContext dbContext)
     {
    
         _dbContext = dbContext;
     }

    //...other code....

    [HttpPost]
    public  IActionResult Index(RoadRecord model)
    {
        //select the newest datatime from database
        var result = _dbContext.RoadRecords.GroupBy(x => x.LicencePlate).Select(x=>x.Max(z=>z.Date)).ToList();
        
        if (!result.Contains(model.Date))
        {
            //if the record is not the newest one, The controller will not change the data and response the error message.
            ModelState.AddModelError("","you can only change the newest record");
             var listmodel =  _dbContext.RoadRecords.ToList();
             return View(listmodel);
            
        }
        else
        {
            //if the record is the newest one,the controller will update the data in db.
            
            //.......
        }
    }
}
```

Then add

```
<div asp-validation-summary="All" class="text-danger"></div>
```

In your View, Once user update the uncorrest record, The view will show the error message.

[image]

**Or** you can use `FluentValidation` to custom your validation rules, But i think it will be more complex.

Comment: Thank you! And there is a way, to dont let the user to reach the Record's edit page?
I mean, not only just unable to edit the record, but unable to go to the edit page if its not newest. Not with link too.

Comment: I Think when you load the page in get method, You can find the newest data first and pass it to the view, Then in your view, Use `$.onload(xx)` to get the data of each item and Compare with the data passed from controller when page load, and hide the button if they are not the same. In my opinion, Is it really worth it? Do the same thing with more code.

Comment: Its ugly if I cant edit a record but there is the Edit button

Comment: Sorry for my expression, I meant to hide the buttons for those records whose dates do not meet the requirements.